# How to save Paypal credit card transaction details into database using php?

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I want to store Payment transaction details(e.g., transaction_id , payment amount , payment status, date , userid etc.) after payment by credit card on Paypal ,  into database same as we stores transaction details from Paypal.

I have searched but haven't found Solution.

Please suggest me some right solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the sample apps e.g. in node https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-nodejs (samples apps also there for rails, php, java, dotnet, python) where a full on application is built using paypal rest apis and databases are used. Hopefully that should help you.